# python: How to check extra requirements at runtime?

Tags: python, pkg-resources

Our main application has some extra features, that users can enable. Those features are in their own directory. Those features might need extra dependencies. I am considering to put those in a `requires.txt` file there. At runtime, we would like to let people know, if the feature will break. I am currently considering something like this:

```
def checkfeature(feature):
  everything_okay = True
  f = pkg_resources.resource_stream(feature, "requires.txt")
  with f:
    for r in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(f):
      if pkg_resources.working_set.find(r) is None:
        print "%r not found, please install, otherwise this feature does not work" % (r,)
        everything_okay = False
  return everything_okay
```

Is this the right, pythonic way of doing things? Does this make sense?

Small update:
Why so complex and not just `try: import ... except ImportError: ...` like suggested in one answer:

1. Our plugins might have a bunch of dependencies. Creating actual code like the one below is quite verbose.
2. Some plugins might need a specific version of a package. Testing that requires either a pakcage specific test or using `pkg_resources` anyway. So that's why my idea above uses pkg_resources.
3. We want to run unit tests for plugins that can be run. Handling the ImportError in the unit tests is not nice. Having a `can_we_unit_test_this_plugin(plugin)` function makes things easier.

Second update: What about `extra_require` in `setup.py`?

1. people miss to install those often. Okay, bad excuse.
2. My vision is, that `setup.py` loads the `extra_require` straight from the above mentioned `requires.txt` in the individual subdirs for the individual features. But that's really the next step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, you just try to *import* the dependency, and handle the `ImportError` exception gracefully:

```
try:
    import dependency
except ImportError:
    # dependency missing, issue a warning
    import warnings
    warnings.warn('dependency not found, please install to enable xyz feature')
```

You can list such dependencies in the `extras_require` entry of your setuptools-based `setup.py` script. `pip`, `easy_install` and `zc.buildout` all can handle installing such extras. See [Declaring “Extras” (optional features with their own dependencies)](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies).

You can use the `extras_require` entry to list minimal version requirements if you have those. Yes, there is a possibility that the user already has an older version of the dependency installed; I'd just document the requirements clearly. Really, test for *features*, not versions. If you need a newer version because a certain API method has been added? Test for that method rather than for the version.

However, it sounds as if you may want to package the plugins as *separate* packages instead, then list *those* in `extras_require`. I'd use [entry points](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#entry-points) to register and enumerate such plugins. That way you do *not* need to test for imports *or* for packages, you just enumerate over registered entry points instead. Each plugin lists their own dependencies and has it's own unit tests.

Comment: Okay, I should have added, that we might need a specific version of a specific package. And I should have added, that we would like to know in advance, if a feature will work. Because that's a way of enabling unit tests for that feature. I will improve my question shortly.

Comment: I also appended a note on `extra_require` to my question. I see that as a different part of the story. About feature checking: Yes, that's usually a good thing, but can sometimes be very ugly. Especially, if you hit complex bugs in specific versions. Also note: The above checkfeature is not the only way of checking. The feature in question can add to that function on its own.

Comment: @Elrond: expanded; you want to separate out the plugins into separate packages, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Really, test for features, not versions" => What about fixes, security patches? Maybe you know that something works on version X, but cannot tell for sure if it's going to be okay on anything lower.

Comment: @LukeMarlin: those are the exception, not the rule, though. And you'd generally use version ranges in `extras_require` to ensure you get the fixed versions.